# Filtering only one of a list of unique values using dplyr

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

Okay so I have a dataframe as follows in R:

```
df <- structure(list(Job_Bin = c("EXECUTIVE", 
"EXECUTIVE", "EXECUTIVE", 
"STAFF ASSISTANTS", "STAFF ASSISTANTS", 
"STAFF ASSISTANTS", "STAFF ASSISTANTS", 
"STAFF ASSISTANTS", "BARREL RIDER", 
"BARREL RIDER"), Code = c("101", 
"101", "101", "102", "102", "102", "102", "102", "103", "103"
)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

It's a lookup table and basically I just want to extract the first instance of a `Code` .

Final goal:

```
Job_Bin             Code
EXECUTIVE           101
STAFF ASSISTANTS    102
BARREL RIDER        103
```

I would like to do this using dplyr/tidyverse if possible.

I tried using the following but it returned an error:

```
df %>% 
  filter(unique(Code))

Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 422 or 1, not size 120.
i Input `..1` is `unique(Code)`.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `distinct` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    distinct
```

If it is based on a single column

```
df %>%

   distinct(Job_Bin, .keep_all = TRUE)
#           Job_Bin Code
#1        EXECUTIVE  101
#2 STAFF ASSISTANTS  102
#3     BARREL RIDER  103
```

---

Or `unique` in base R`

```
unique(df)
```

Comment: @JohnThomas with `tidyverse`, this is the canonical way.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this `base R` solution:

```
#Code
dfnew <- df[!duplicated(df$Job_Bin),]
```

Or:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code 2
dfnew <- df %>% filter(!duplicated(Job_Bin))
```

The output will be in both cases:

```
           Job_Bin Code
1        EXECUTIVE  101
2 STAFF ASSISTANTS  102
3     BARREL RIDER  103
```

Comment: sure, but dplyr?

Comment: @JohnThomas Added an update with `dplyr`. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

df %>% distinct(Job_Bin, Code, .keep_all = TRUE)

Output:

[image]